# DidDisappear is called from the other thread and with delay

Tags: ios

After pressing on a button in a custom tableview cell I perform an asynch operation and in the selector callback call:

[`self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_PURCHASE_SEGUE sender:self];`

So the next callback is called:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
}
```

and I can see in log that the new screen's `viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear` methods already were called but the next screen will be shown only in several seconds after this.

What problem can be here?

**CODE:**

```
-(void) moveToPurchaseScreen{

     NSLog(@"view1 moveToPurchaseScreen");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_PURCHASE_SEGUE sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"view1 prepareForSegue");
//    
//    BSPurchaseViewController *purchaseViewController = [segue destinationViewController];    
//    purchaseViewController.pngImage = [BSSharedObject getInstance].createdImage;
////    [[BSPopupManager getInstance]closeWaitingPopup];
//    
//    
//     NSLog(@"2");
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"view1 DidDisappear");
}

2012-10-10 21:51:15.644 BarneyShop[4961:11603] view1 moveToPurchaseScreen
2012-10-10 21:51:15.646 BarneyShop[4961:11603] view1 prepareForSegue
2012-10-10 21:51:15.647 BarneyShop[4961:11603] view2 viewDidLoad
2012-10-10 21:51:15.648 BarneyShop[4961:11603] view2 viewWillAppear
2012-10-10 21:51:23.812 BarneyShop[4961:f803] view1 DidDisappear
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
[purchase initPurchase: self withSelector:@selector(moveToPurchaseScreen)andProduct:product];


-(void) initPurchase:(id)object withSelector:(SEL)selector andProduct:(Product *)product{

    [operationQueue cancelAllOperations];

    NSInvocationOperation *downloadImageOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[BSImageDownloader getInstance] selector:@selector(downloadImageSync:) object:URL_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE];

    NSInvocationOperation *createImageOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[BSImageCreator getInstance] selector:@selector(createImage:) object:product];

    NSInvocationOperation *saveImageOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[BSImageSaver getInstance] selector:@selector(saveImageAsPng:) object:nil];

    NSInvocationOperation *callbackOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:object selector:selector object:nil];

    [createImageOperation addDependency:downloadImageOperation];
    [saveImageOperation addDependency:createImageOperation];
    [callbackOperation addDependency:saveImageOperation];

    [operationQueue addOperation:downloadImageOperation];
    [operationQueue addOperation:createImageOperation];
    [operationQueue addOperation:saveImageOperation];
    [operationQueue addOperation:callbackOperation];    

}
```

Comment: What's the "async operation" you perform? Can we see the code for that?

Comment: I see 3ms difference between viewDidLoad1 and viewWillAppear. Where are those several seconds you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated]; // <-- Try adding this.

    NSLog(@"view1 DidDisappear");
}
```

Let me know if this speeds up your process. I also noticed that this method gets called from a different thread. Are you calling it manually?

**EDIT**

Try this as well:

```
-(void) moveToPurchaseScreen{

    NSLog(@"view1 moveToPurchaseScreen");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_PURCHASE_SEGUE sender:self];
    });
}
```

Comment: the same result:

2012-10-10 21:59:34.669 BarneyShop[5198:17107] view2 viewWillAppear
2012-10-10 21:59:42.297 BarneyShop[5198:f803] view1 DidDisappear

Comment: Simon, many thanks, it solved the problem.
As I understand I get a callback from not the main thread, so I call
performSegueWithIdentifier from not a main thread - so I have delay with viewDidDisappear

Comment: Correct. `NSOperationQueue` manages threading on its own. It may be using the main thread, if it's not doing anything, but there's no way to know for sure. That way, you're sure you're on the main thread. Besides, you don't have to use GCD functions to achieve that, you could use `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]` instead.